# Failed inserting record into consumer table not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, postgresql, bulkinsert

I'm trying to insert data that I got from a csv file to tables that I previously created using sqlalchemy in python. However, when I try running the following code I get an error message that says that not all arguments were converted during string formatting.
Could you help me identify what my error is and how can I fix it?

````
#Importing the csv input file
df = pd.read_csv('APAN5310_HW6_DATA.csv')
print (df)
print (df.columns)
df.dtypes

#Splitting the data for the first table
first_name = df['first_name']
last_name = df['last_name']
email = df['email']
df[['cell_phone','home_phone']] = df.cell_and_home_phones.str.split(";",expand=True,)
cell_phone = df['cell_phone']
home_phone = df['home_phone']
consumer_list = [first_name, last_name, email, cell_phone, home_phone]

import psycopg2

def bulkInsert(records):
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                      password="123",
                                      host="localhost",
                                      port="5432",
                                      database="Pharmacy")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO consumer (consumer_list) 
                           VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) """

        # executemany() to insert multiple rows
        result = cursor.executemany(sql_insert_query, records)
        connection.commit()
        print(cursor.rowcount, "Record inserted successfully into consumer table")

    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print("Failed inserting record into consumer table {}".format(error))

    finally:
        # closing database connection.
        if connection:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")

records = consumer_list
bulkInsert(records)```

Error Message I get
"Failed inserting record into consumer table not all arguments converted during string formatting
PostgreSQL connection is closed"
````

Comment: Your INSERT SQL is incorrect. It needs to have all of the columns listed within the first `()` after the table name.

Answer (score 0):

@Javier you have to convert all arguments to columns.... as @mechanical_meat said:
""" INSERT INTO consumer (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)
VALUES (%s,     %s,       %s,      %s,      %s) """

But I suppose that you found that in a year.